# Display comma separated values as list items:

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, angular

This is a continuation from this question: [How to display comma delimited JSON value as a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44729743/how-to-display-comma-delimited-json-value-as-a-list)

I have this array:

```
var ARTISTS: Artist[] = [
  {
     "name": "Barot Bellingham",
     "shortname": "Barot_Bellingham",
     "reknown": "Royal Academy of Painting and Sculpture",
     "bio": "Some bio here...",
     "friends": [
       "james",
       "harry",
       "bob"
    ]
  },
  // etc...
]
```

And I need to display "friends" as an ordered list. I'm doing so like this:

```
<li *ngFor="let friend of artist.friends">{{friend}}</li>
```

This works perfectly, *but*, I now need to restructure my data so that there is no nested array:

```
var ARTISTS: Artist[] = [
  {
     "name": "Barot Bellingham",
     "shortname": "Barot_Bellingham",
     "reknown": "Royal Academy of Painting and Sculpture",
     "bio": "Some bio here...",
     "friends": "James, Harry, Bob"
  }
```

How can I continue to display each friend as separate list items, such as:

```
<ol>
  <li>James</li>
  <li>Harry</li>
  <li>Bob</li>
</ol>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the `toString()` method to display the list of a string separated by commas.

```js
var friends = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
console.log(friends.toString());
```

So in your case you could just change this:

```
<li *ngFor="let friend of artist.friends">{{friend}}</li>
```

to this for example:

```
<div>{{artist.friends.toString()}}</div>
```

If you want to change the separator, or add a space after the commas, you can use the `join()` method of arrays too:

```js
var friends = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
console.log(friends.join(', '));
```

Instead if now you have in your model the list as a string separated by comma, use the `ng-repeat` recreating an array from the string in this way:

```
<li *ngFor="let friend of artist.friends.split(', ')">{{friend}}</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, quirimmo! But, I fear I was a bit unclear in my question. See my edit at the very bottom of the question: by list items, I literally mean `<li>James</li><li>Harry</li><li>Bob</li>`. I'm having trouble rendering this comma separated value to where each friend is wrapped in `<li></li>` tags. Or, does your answer explain this, and I'm am just misunderstanding? Thanks!

Comment: I think I got you now, edited the answer. Actually you should be able to do that just using: `<li *ngFor="let friend of artist.friends.split(', ')">{{friend}}</li>`

Comment: THANK YOU! Just what I was trying to do. Sometimes the little things screw me up!